# App is crashing while intending navigation drawer activity

Tags: android

I want to start the navigation drawer activity when pressing a button.
Here's my code:-

```
public void logdinScreen(View view) {
    codeM = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    if(codeM.getText().toString().equals("0000"))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"LogedIn",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(OTPScreen.this,HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.harpreet.btp_project" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category  android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OTPScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_otpscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:-

```
05-23 01:08:23.999    3326-3326/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-23 01:08:24.059    3326-3326/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-23 01:08:24.059    3326-3326/? D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-23 01:08:24.059    3326-3326/? D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-23 01:08:24.059    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-23 01:08:24.239    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 35% free 12967K/19779K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
05-23 01:08:24.259    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 29.330MB for 8294416-byte allocation
05-23 01:08:24.289    3326-3328/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 25% free 21066K/27911K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 35ms
05-23 01:08:24.429    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-23 01:08:24.449    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-23 01:08:24.459    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-23 01:08:24.469    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Merge)
    Build Date: 07/09/13 Tue
    Local Branch: AU_41
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
05-23 01:08:24.529    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-23 01:08:39.009    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-23 01:08:39.009    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413e2378)
05-23 01:08:39.029    3326-3326/com.example.harpreet.btp_project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.harpreet.btp_project/com.example.harpreet.btp_project.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.harpreet.btp_project.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.harpreet.btp_project.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:100)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:816)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:72)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:804)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.harpreet.btp_project.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The app is working untill i press that button. When i comment the intent part and uncomment the Toast part, it is working perfect.
Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: can you explain what is not working correctly? paste logcat error if its throwing one.

Comment: The app is working untill i press that button.
When i comment the intent part and uncomment the Toast part, it is working perfect.

Comment: can you copy the logcat error and also the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: looking through the logcat, you have a NullPointerException on line 100 of your NavigationDrawerFragment. If you post your code for that class we will be close to solving the issue

Comment: @leibreichb1:mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));

Comment: @leibreichb1:The above was code at 100th line.

Comment: I assume you have already called mDrawerListView = ...  If so the getActionBar().getThemedContext() might be returning null.